# Using Tensorflow-Lite GPU delegate in Android's Native environment with C-API

Tags: c, android-ndk, delegates, gpu, tensorflow-lite

#### Info

I'm using Tensorflow-Lite in Android's Native environment via the C-API (following [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#use_tflite_c_api)) but runtime is significantly longer compared to the GPU delegate via the Java API (on ART).

The [JNI AAR file (2.2)](https://bintray.com/google/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite#files/org%2Ftensorflow%2Ftensorflow-lite%2F2.2.0) offers C-headers and a shared-library, but it seems that the shared-library doesn't contain the GPU delegate, but only a framework to configure delegates on (`TfLiteDelegate` object and `TfLiteDelegateCreate()`).

** It doesn't provide any `TfLiteGpuDelegateV2Create()` or `tflite` namespace access, for example.

#### Trials

- I've tried to include a `libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so` in the project with **cmake** but though it seems to build and link OK - the library isn't accessible via Native code.
- I tried following [c_api.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7a93fd22f78231a64abb212dffa15d9749da1281/tensorflow/lite/c/c_api.h)'s example of delegate usage, but I can't seem to configure a GPU delegate.
- Docker container doesn't include toolchain (trying to build shared library in [tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/latest-devel-gpu/images/sha256-a5d4548223d0949503efe9bb3ef8ec29e51eeca1a347afe8485aacc9d0ca31da?context=explore) Tensorflow Docker image with `bazel build -c opt --config android_arm64 tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so` fails with `cc_toolchain_suite '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'arm64-v8a'`)

#### Question

How can I run an inference with the **GPU delegate** in Android's **Native** environment using the **C-API**?

Comment: Good question, I have the same question somebody to help us?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it as follows:

#### 1. Clone and configure `tensorflow`

Clone `tensorflow` repo from GitHub, `cd` into it and run `./configure`. There it is important to answer
`Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]`
with `y` and correctly specify the Android NDK and SDK directories.

#### 2. Build `libtensorflow-lite_gpu_delegate` with `bazel`

I succeeded building the GPU delegate shared library with

```
bazel build -c opt --cxxopt=--std=c++11 --config android_arm64 tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so
```

I built against Android NDK `18.1.5063045` with minimum API level 27. Note that I only tested for the `android_arm64` architecture, I cannot give guarantees for other architectures.

(The time I compiled TensorFlow the `HEAD` pointed at commit `0f8a27183657972c8ba2bce150e1364179ded6f9`.)

#### 3. Update `CMakeLists.txt`

The relevant lines are the following:

```
include_directories(
    /Users/<name>/tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu # for Mac 
)

add_library(tensorflow-lite_gpu_delegate SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(tensorflow-lite_gpu_delegate PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    /private/var/tmp/_bazel_<name>/fe60511640322ef6962b77bab4b291e3/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/arm64-v8a-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so) # I obtained this path pressing Cmd+Option+C on the libtensorflow-lite_gpu_delegate.so file on Mac, might be different on your OS

target_link_libraries(
    tensorflow-lite_gpu_delegate
    )
```

#### 4. Use GPU delegate in code

The relevant lines are the following:

```
#include <delegate.h>

auto *delegate = TfLiteGpuDelegateV2Create(/*default options=*/nullptr);

// Create the model and interpreter options.
TfLiteModel *model = TfLiteModelCreate(/* create as usual */);
TfLiteInterpreterOptions* options = TfLiteInterpreterOptionsCreate();
TfLiteInterpreterOptionsAddDelegate(options, delegate);

// Create the interpreter.
TfLiteInterpreter *interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, options);
```

**Note**: For me, the GPU delegate did not yield a great improvement in inference speed. This might be due to my model using operations that are not supported by the GPU delegate (the set of supported ops seems to be [quite small](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced#supported_ops) right now) and therefore have to be computed on CPU.